# How to define Auto evaluation and attempted multiple times constraint in MCQ for django model?

Tags: python-3.6, django-2.2

I am working on a MCQ based django project and based on my research I have below models that I got from 3rd party reference. Of course I had to make some modification based on my custom need. below is the snippet from models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    questions_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    roll_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created', ]
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizzes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    marks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    optional = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class QuizTakers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Response(models.Model):
    quiztaker = models.ForeignKey(QuizTakers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.label


@receiver(post_save, sender=Quiz)
def set_default_quiz(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(id=instance.id)
    quiz.update(questions_count=instance.question_set.filter(quiz=instance.pk).count())


@receiver(post_save, sender=Question)
def set_default(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(id=instance.quiz.id)
    quiz.update(questions_count=instance.quiz.question_set.filter(quiz=instance.quiz.pk).count())


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Quiz)
def slugify_title(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)
```

However, there are couple of points that I have implement for my MCQs for which I am not able to find proper solution. Below are the points.

```
1) Every quiz can be attempted multiple times by the quiz taker. No restriction.
2) Since the questions are in MCQ format, the quiz taker answers are auto-evaluated by the application.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer both your questions:

1. Since every quiz can be done multiple times you will simply have a reset button. Once that button is clicked, it will delete the QuizTaker. You will then be able to create it again.
2. When you create a quiz all the questions have answers and one of those answers is correct. Therefore, you can define a function that checks if the response provided is equal to the correct answer then increment the number of correct answers by 1 for each correct answer.

I hope this helps!!